# how to change timestamp format without seconds in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i tried to change the timestamp format without the second in php but i think there is something wrong when i change the format

this is what i already tried

```
'SELECT 
    user_review.*, 
    data_movie.*, 
    users.username, 
    user_review.DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"') AS formatted_date
FROM data_movie 
INNER JOIN user_review 
INNER JOIN users ON data_movie.id = user_review.id_movie 
WHERE genre LIKE "'. $genre .'%" 
ORDER BY created_at desc'
```

please help how to make it right

Comment: Try `DATE_FORMAT(user_review.created_at, '"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"')`

Comment: but how to implement it in my code above? where should i put it? i've tried that @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : this is still partially buggy. Check the single quote for string concatenation

Comment: @Cid Yes...I saw that, but I assumed the OP had some escaping needs given that it is in PHP code.

Comment: Is there any error message given? What exacly do you mean by "something wrong"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code :

1) `user_review.DATE_FORMAT(created_at, ...)` is not valid SQL syntax, should be written as `DATE_FORMAT(user_review.created_at, ...)`

2) You have additional double quotes in the format specifier : `'"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"'` should be written `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'`

3) The `INNER JOIN` on `user_review` is invalid, as it is missing an `ON` clause to express the join conditions. It actually seems to be mixed with the next join on `users`. I assumed that you have a relationship between `user_review.user_id` and `users.id` (you might need to adapt that clause to match your table structures)

4) In the `WHERE` clause, the right side of the `LIKE` operator should be enclosed between single quotes instead of double quotes.

Here is your updated query. I changed the surrounding quotes from single to double to make it easier to embedd single quotes in the query.

```
"SELECT 
    user_review.*, 
    data_movie.*, 
    users.username, 
    DATE_FORMAT(user_review.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS formatted_date 
FROM 
    data_movie 
    INNER JOIN user_review ON data_movie.id = user_review.id_movie 
    INNER JOIN users ON user_review.user_id = users.id
WHERE genre LIKE '". $genre ."%' order by created_at desc"
```

Comment: Now *this* is an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the complete explanation. it works now

Comment: Thanks @FunkFortyNiner !

Comment: Welcome @QubaisyAndiyantama

Answer (score -2):

Try this way in your php code, you have mistakes in all your " and ':

```
$query="SELECT user_review.*, data_movie.*, users.username, DATE_FORMAT(user_review.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS formatted_date 
        FROM data_movie 
        INNER JOIN user_review 
        INNER JOIN users ON data_movie.id = user_review.id_movie 
        WHERE genre LIKE '". $genre ."%' order by created_at desc";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "try this"? Can you explain the crucial parts?

Comment: You've fixed the `DATE_FORMAT()`. But read carefully the query again. Every parts.

Comment: @QubaisyAndiyantama so please accept and validate the answer

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
SELECT user_review.*, data_movie.*, 
users.username, 
DATE_FORMAT(user_review.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS formatted_date 
FROM data_movie INNER JOIN user_review INNER JOIN users ON data_movie.id = user_review.id_movie WHERE genre LIKE "'. $genre .'%" ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: Just saying "Try this" can be taken as this analogy: Say somebody told you to "try this" little yellow or blue pill, what would you tell that person? Personally, I'd ask them why I should try/take that pill, asking them also what it is and what does it do. Surely there must be a reason why someone should try that pill, *right?* Think about that for a minute.